# Area recognition in image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have this image. 
[Image of a map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrB1g.jpg)

I want to:-
1. Recognize all the regions in this image
2. Recognize which region is connected to other regions

My goal is to apply four color theorem in this image and output a properly colored image. I'm a beginner in both python and opencv.

Your assistance in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a MATLAB code which does what you want. It shouldn't be too complicated to implement it in Python+OpenCV:

```
% read image
m = rgb2gray(imread('map.jpg')); 
% remove noise
m = medfilt2(m);
b = m < 250;
se1 = strel('disk',1,0);
se2 = ones(7);
b = imclose(imopen(b,se1),se2);
% skeletonize
B = bwmorph(b,'skel',inf);
% remove background
R = padarray(~B,[1 1],1);
bg = bwselect(R,1,1,4);
R(bg) = 0;
R = R(2:end-1,2:end-1);
% get regions connected components
ccRegions = bwconncomp(R,4);
maskRegions = false([size(R),ccRegions.NumObjects]);
MAP = zeros(size(R));
% generate a binary mask for each region, dilate it to detect overlaps
% between neigbors
for ii = 1:ccRegions.NumObjects
    maskRegions((ii - 1)*numel(R) + (ccRegions.PixelIdxList{ii})) = 1;
    maskRegions(:,:,ii) = imdilate(maskRegions(:,:,ii),se1);
    MAP(maskRegions(:,:,ii)) = ii;
end
% detect neighbors using masks overlapping
neighborsRegions = cell(ccRegions.NumObjects,1);
for ii = 1:ccRegions.NumObjects
    r = repmat(maskRegions(:,:,ii),[1 1 ccRegions.NumObjects]);
    idxs = any(any(r & maskRegions,1),2); %indexes of touching neighbors
    idxs(ii) = 0; % remove self index
    neighborsRegions{ii} = find(idxs);
end
% show result
imshow(MAP,[])
c = regionprops(ccRegions,'Centroid');
for ii = 1:ccRegions.NumObjects
    text(c(ii).Centroid(1),c(ii).Centroid(2),num2str(ii),'FontSize',20,'Color','r');
end
```

The output looks like that:[image]

And the neighbors of each region is:

```
neighborsRegions = {[2;3]
                    [1;3;4]
                    [1;2;4;5;6]
                    [2;3;6]
                    [3;6]
                    [3;4;5]
                    []}
```

Comment: Thanks so much brother.